# Factor where clauses into subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm wondering if its always possible in SQL to factor a where condition through a join to a subquery. For instance, if I have

```
select ... from a join b on ... where p and q
```

and `p` pertains only to `a`, `q` to `b`, then can I always rewrite as?

```
select ... from (select ... from a where p) as a join (select ... from b where q) as b on ...
```

Thanks!

[Notes: 1) I'm using postgres in case this affects the answer. 2) Readability is not an important consideration, as these are automatically generated queries. **Edit**: 3) I'm not only interested in inner join but other joins as well.]

Comment: Why not select ... from a join b on (... and q) where p? I mean why not put the conditions directly into the ON clause of the join? Of course condition on the first table must stay in the WHERE. Using subselects may hinder query execution optimization.

Comment: 1) Does putting conditions in "on" make any difference? 2) If using subselects may hinder optimization, should I try to factor conditions out then? I would think that if the condition makes one side of the join much smaller it could also help to have factored in.

Comment: Putting conditions in join does not effect the result. But having all the conditions on a single table in one place may help the optimizer do its work.

Comment: Wait... you added that you're interested in OUTER JOINs also. This changes things a bit. Conditions in the WHERE cannot be moved into the ON clause of OUTER JOINS or into subSELECTs without consequences. At least not always. It depends on the conditions and NULLs.

Comment: Aha ... ok -- that was the case I was worried about. :) So ... lets see: If I have a condition on the outside that filters out all matches of a row in 'a' and I put on inside, then I'll get the row in a with nulls for b. Thanks -- I knew there was a fly in the ointment somewhere but forgot where. If you write that up as an answer I'll accept it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the query 1:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON <SomeForeignKey>
JOIN TableC ON <SomeForeignKey>
WHERE <SomeConditionOnTableA> AND
      <SomeConditionOnTableB> AND
      <SomeConditionOnTableC>
```

... is equivalent to the query 2:

```
SELECT ...
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB ON <SomeForeignKey> AND <SomeConditionOnTableB>
JOIN TableC ON <SomeForeignKey> AND <SomeConditionOnTableC>
WHERE <SomeConditionOnTableA>
```

But the same is not true if instead of (INNER) JOINs you use OUTER JOINs. With OUTER JOINs the equivalency holds for very simple conditions that match NOT NULL column values, like:

```
name='value'
name LIKE '%value%'
number < const
field IN (...)
```

Notice that these are all conditions that make the OUTER JOINs moot anyway, as they are filtering out rows that have NULL values in the envolved columns... so they would filter out also the rows added by the OUTER JOIN not retrieving anything from the joined table.

But the equivalency breaks if you use OUTER JOINs and start comparing column values with NULLs or comparing expressions that may envolve NULLs.

For example, taking this query (formatted as query 1):

```
SELECT ...
FROM      TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON <SomeForeignKey>
LEFT JOIN TableC c ON <SomeForeignKey>
WHERE a.somefield = 'whatever'
  AND b.name IS NOT NULL
  AND c.somenumber >100
```

In this case the filter is applied after having resolved the OUTER JOIN, and it eliminates both the rows that exist in TableB and have a NULL name, but also removes the rows that where added by the OUTER JOIN not finding a matching row in TableB. This is **not** equivalent to the query 2 format:

```
SELECT ...
FROM      TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON <SomeForeignKey> AND b.name IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN TableC c ON <SomeForeignKey> AND c.somenumber >100
WHERE a.somefield = 'whatever'
```

In this case the filter is applied to TableB before resolving the OUTER JOIN. TableB rows that have a NULL name are eliminated by the filter, but reintroduced by the LEFT JOIN. So this query might contain rows that the former does not.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, I can't think of a situation where it is not possible. WHERE in it self can be replaced with a join:

```
select ... from A where x=10
<=>
select ... from A join ( values (10) ) B (x) on A.x = B.x
```

Perhaps off topic, but for transformations in general Vadim Tropashko (http://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0501053) shows that it is possible to reduce the set of classic relational algebra operators to two binary operations: natural join and generalized union

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Hmm... so this applies to outer joins as well? I can't think of anything either but have some half recollection of an odd edge case in my mind.